# Prediction variance function in R

Tags: r, time-series

In the `ar.ols()` function in R, the prediction variance can be printed through the returned object `$var.pred`.

Can the `arima()` function in R also print out prediction variance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arima()` object has `$sigma2` which is the maximum likelihood estimation of the variance of the error terms. It is basically the same variable with the `$var.pred` of `ar()`

Comment: Actually i do not know if i should estimate using MLE or OLS. The two approaches may sometimes have some difference in estimated values. Both have different theories behind them. But ar.ols() function seem to estimate a mean that is close to zero, but MLE in arima() function does not estimate using OLS